# How can I group by a single column of the format "a,b,c" loaded from a hive table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I'm definitely a newbie and I bet there's an easy answer.  My code looks like this:

```
A = load 'table1' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader() as (userid1: chararray, location: chararray, age: int);
```

the location column in hive looks like this: `city,state,country`

This is what I'm doing:

```
B= GROUP A BY location;
C= FOREACH B GENERATE
    group as location,
    SUM(rating) as RatingSum,
    AVG(rating) as RatingAverage,
    MIN(rating) as RatingMin,
    MAX(rating) as RatingMax,
    COUNT(rating) as RecNum;
```

The C won't work, probably because this is the output from B:

```
(, ,,{(56072,, ,,,56072,1885171218,3),(104462,, ,,,104462,8486054060,7),(46927,, ,,47,46927,0749300523,0),(46927,, ,,47,46927,0749300515,0),(64139,, ,,,64139,8422665662,0),(112345,, ,,39,112345,0375727345,7),(151458,, ,,,151458,1551667959,0),(64139,, ,,,64139,8422676095,6)})
(ny, ,,{(175362,ny, ,,,175362,0446604844,10)})
(, usa,,{(223496,, usa,,,223496,0714838500,7)})
(gap, ,,{(211944,gap, ,,42,211944,044023722X,9),(211944,gap, ,,42,211944,1577486445,8),(211944,gap, ,,42,211944,0821767089,9),(211944,gap, ,,42,211944,0804106304,0),(211944,gap, ,,42,211944,0743412621,9),(211944,gap, ,,42,211944,0505521474,7),(211944,gap, ,,42,211944,0440236673,9),(211944,gap, ,,42,211944,0440225701,0),(211944,gap, ,,42,211944,044022165X,0),(211944,gap, ,,42,211944,0440214041,0),(211944,gap, ,,42,211944,0440213525,0),(211944,gap, ,,42,211944,044020111X,0),(211944,gap, ,,42,211944,0425151867,0),(211944,gap, ,,42,211944,0385472951,8),(211944,gap, ,,42,211944,0373832257,7),(211944,gap, ,,42,211944,0373471521,5),(211944,gap, ,,42,211944,0373291574,6),(211944,gap, ,,42,211944,0373291566,7),(211944,gap, ,,42,211944,0373201532,7),(211944,gap, ,,42,211944,0373151861,8),(211944,gap, ,,42,211944,158660242X,0)})
(n/a, ,,{(169489,n/a, ,,,169489,0618150730,6)})
```

I'm sure I need to change my load statement or add a step before grouping or both but I'm lost. Please help.  As you may gather, the original hive table was created from a csv with a semicolon as a separator.  if it helps, here's the code I used to create the table in hive:

```
     create table table1 (UserID string, Location string, Age INT) 
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
    WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("separatorChar" = '\u0059') STORED AS TEXTFILE
 tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

Comment: Where is the rating column coming from? Your load has 3 fields and none of them is rating !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming rating is one of the columns you are loading in A, you have to use A.rating in C.

```
C= FOREACH B GENERATE
    group as location,
    SUM(A.rating) as RatingSum,
    AVG(A.rating) as RatingAverage,
    MIN(A.rating) as RatingMin,
    MAX(A.rating) as RatingMax,
    COUNT(A.rating) as RecNum;
```